# GoogleMaps: Setting a marker on user click

Tags: google-maps

Currently I'm trying to set markers on a map based on user clicks. I have tried everything I can think of and NOTHING works. It seems as though my map doesn't even detect clicks. Currently, I'm trying to keep the script as simple as possible, I'm just trying to detect clicks on the map at this point:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() 
    {
        <!-- Set the initial location-->
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44, -71);

        <!-- initialization options -->
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        <!-- The map variable
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        <!-- END INITIALIZE -->
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function placeMarker(location) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
       });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
       placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
</script>
```

I've tried so many variants on this sort of code, every it never works. If I change it to "addDomListener(window, ...)" it works, but never using the map as the listener. Ideas?

EDIT: OK, solved it by changing the function somewhat and changing its location in the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            <!-- Set the initial location -->
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44, -71);

            <!-- initialization options -->
            var myOptions = {
                minZoom: 3,
                zoom: 8,
                maxZoom: 9,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };  
            <!-- The map variable-->
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            <!-- Add the functionality of placing a marker on a click-->
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latLng,
                    map: map
                   });
                alert('You clicked the map.'+event.latLng);
            }); 
            <!-- END INITIALIZE -->
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        <!-- Add the functionality of placing a marker on a click-->
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map
               });
            alert('You clicked the map.'+event.latLng);
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: do you have running code we could look at that demonstrates the issue? Or a jsfiddle with all the code we could look at?

Comment: BTW, you're referencing the LatLng object within the LatLng object in line 2 of your code (i.e., clickedLocation).  You're already passing a LatLng from the click as the locatin variable.

Comment: Good point andresf, and Mano Marks, I'll update the code to include all of my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you place this code in improper place (or do it in improper time). Recently I've encountered with the same problem and it took some time to solve it. Look what works for me:

```
var mapservice = {};

mapservice.map = {};
mapservice.options = {};
mapservice.putMarker = {};

mapservice.init = function (divName, textSearch)
{
    this.options =
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map($(divName)[0], this.options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function (event)
    {
        mapservice.putMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    }
mapservice.putMarker = function (location)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this skeleton code (edited to suit my purposes) sadly didn't work  :(